# Filter GridView depending on userid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linqdatasource

I have a `GridView` which I am binding using a `LinqDataSource`. I want to filter the `GridView` based on the value of the userid (which is stored in a `Session`). I also have a `Session` for determining if the user is an admin.

1. If only user - Filter `GridView` to user_id(column) == Session["userid"]
2. If admin - Show all user_ids.

I've managed to filter it in numerous ways for the user but not how to later display everything for the admin (admin has the user_id = 1).

Does somebody have any idea?

Here is my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    CausesValidation="False"
    GridLines="None"  
    AllowPaging="True"  
    CssClass="mGrid"  
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataKeyNames="event_id">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="event_id" HeaderText="event_id" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="event_id" InsertVisible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" SortExpression="title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="description" 
            SortExpression="description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="event_start" HeaderText="event_start" 
            SortExpression="event_start" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="event_end" HeaderText="event_end" 
            SortExpression="event_end" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="user_id" 
            SortExpression="user_id" />
    </Columns>

    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
    TableName="calevents" EnableDelete="True" 
    EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" Where="user_id = @user_id">

</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Some of the things I've tried (Manual databinding):

```
    // Registered users may only edit their own events
    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var events = from a in dc.calevents
                 where a.user_id == userId()
                 select a;

    GridView1.DataSource = events;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

or following, which makes me have to override the edit, cancel and update methods.

```
// Registered users may only edit their own events
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["admin"] != "admin")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text != userId().ToString())
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    Label1.Text = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
                }
                else
                    GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something  like follwoing...

```
page_load()
{
   if user is not admin put folllowing...

       LinqDataSource2.Where = "user_id = @user_id"

   else

      do not filter

}
```

So This way you can do this.. at moment since the Admin id is 1 it filter rocord for 1.

Comment: Thank you... I solved it with:    

 if (Session["admin"] == null)
            LinqDataSource2.Where = "user_id = " + userId();
        else
            LinqDataSource2.Where = "user_id = @user_id";